# Getting "Uninitialized constant" routing error when loading a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm a beginner to both ruby and rails, and using `Rails 5.17` to develop a web app for a class.

Creating the empty Rails project was successful, but something is going wrong when creating a new controller. I generated a new controller named `cars` from the root of the project, which was successful. There was a file in app/controllers named `cars_controller.rb` which looks like this:

```
 class CarsController < ApplicationController
 end
```

I added a method to this file named `hello` that does nothing.

I then created a file named `cars.html.erb` in the `app/views/layouts` directory. This file is a basic page of html code.

In `config/routes.rb`, I added the following:

```
 get '/cars', to:: 'cars_controller#hello'
 resources: cars
```

After all of this, I ran `rails server`, and opened `localhost:3000` in a browser. This brings up the normal Ruby on Rails welcome page.

But when I go to `localhost:3000/cars`, I get the following:

`Routing Error
uninitialized constant CarsControllerController`

I've tried changing the name of the `cars_controller.rb` file. I've tried changing the name of the class in the controller file from `CarsController` to `Cars`. I've tried many different routes in `routes.rb`. I finally tried uninstalling `Rails 5.17` and installing `Rails 5.13`.

I'm very confused, and I'd be grateful for any advice I can get. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great things about Rails is its preference for convention over configuration. However, for this to really benefit you, you need to stick to doing things “The Rails Way” rather than your own way, wherever possible.

In this case, start by getting rid of your custom `get` route, and just use `resources :cars`.

From the command line, run `rake routes` (you might be able to run `rails routes` on your rails version too) and see the routes that it has created for you.

Now, rename the method you added to your `CarsController` from `hello` to `index`.

Move your `hello.html.erb` file from `app/views/layout` to `app/views/cars/index.html.erb`.

Finally, start the rails server (`rails start`) and load the url `http://localhost:3000/cars` in your browser.

—-

Note that templates in `app/views/layout` have a special purpose. These are used to apply a general template to your views. Look up the use of `layout` within a controller for more details

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in how you had defined your route - you don't need `_controller`.

Instead, try this:

```
get '/cars', to: 'cars#hello'
```

Also, keep in mind that in your `cars` directory you need the view: `hello.html.erb`